# What is wrong with my IOException in my slurp method?

Tags: java, string, exception, ioexception, fileslurp

I am making a slurp method which in essence accepts a File and returns its contents as a String.

I keep getting exception errors and I am not sure why. I don't know if I'm throwing the wrong exception, but I need help on addressing why I am receiving an exception, since I have a hard time understanding them. The error traces back to the line

```
content = new String (Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath())));
```

underneath the try { }.

```
/**
   * Investigate Files.readAllBytes as a means of reading the file.
   * Reading files can fail if the file cannot be opened.
   * Mark this method as dangerous with a throws clause:
   * public static ...(...) throws IOException {
   * @return
   * @throws IOException
   */
  public static String slurp() throws IOException
  {
    String content = "";
    File file = new File(content);

    try
    {
      content = new String (Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath())));
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return content;
  }
```

What the errors say:

```
java.io.IOException: Is a directory
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read(FileDispatcherImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:283)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:250)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.read(FileChannelImpl.java:223)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:65)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:109)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:103)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.read(Files.java:3163)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Files.java:3216)
    at hw2.FileUtilities.slurp(FileUtilities.java:46)
    at hw2.FileUtilities.main(FileUtilities.java:14)
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate I'll post them

Comment: Seems pretty self-explanatory: the path you're providing is a directory, not a file, so reading all bytes fails.

Comment: @JanusVarmarken where does this take place in my code?

Comment: am I suppose to replace the path with a file then? I thought it accepts a directory

Comment: yes, `readAllBytes` is attempting to read bytes from a file, so the `Path` instance you're providing it with should point to a file

Comment: Just update whatever the value `file` has to point to the file you want to read

Comment: @JanusVarmarken what  would be the fix? Do I change getAbsolutePath, but how would I connect it to the file?

Comment: Change `File file = new File(content);` to `File file = new File("/path/to/the/file/you/want/to/read/goes/here.txt");` ?

Comment: @JanusVarmarken I did that fix, however for that line where I expressed up above in my code where the error occurs, do I still leave it the same, or do I need to make changes, because the error is still showing up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200457/discussion-between-janus-varmarken-and-adan-vivero).